# How to make long string of non breakable spaces?

Tags: android, kotlin

I wish to add several nonbreakable spaces to the end of the string

```
"\u00A0".repeat(offset)
```

however, after 6 or 7 spaces, the new one does not add. Does not matter how many I set 10,20,30 string does not move from the edge (in multiline textview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```kotlin
myString.padEnd(myString.length + 1000, "\u00A0")
```

padEnd adds the character to fill given length